# How to add a anchor tag to selected text in the paragraph using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have some text in text area or editor. When i select some of the code and then i click on add link i need to convert the selected text to link. How can i do that using jquery.

Comment: You say 'or editor' - I assume you are referring to a WYSIWYG editor? If so, which are you using?

Comment: only selected text, hmm that selected could be any text from paragraph, is it so ?

Comment: I used [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to solve this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In association with the [Rangyinputs jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/), you could use the following code

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
$("#yourTextAreaId").surroundSelectedText('<a href="' + url + '">', '</a>');
```

Alternatively, for a rich text editor you can check this [simple, lightweight rich text editor](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)

For a simple demonstration of the Rangyinputs plugin function, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGJDa/)

Comment: `surroundSelectedText()` is not a jQuery function.

Comment: naidu askd for javascript or jQuery

Comment: check the above fiddle i used javascript

Comment: You've completely neglected to mention which jQuery plugin you have used to get the surroundSelectedText() function. Using only jQuery or vanilla JS, there simply is no surroundSelectedText() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than just links in your editor, something like a complete WYSIWYG editor, try [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Otherwise, if it's just a convenience linking function you need, let the user paste the URL and try my [jQuery urlTolink plugin](http://gabrielizaias.com/articles/jquery-urltolink-plugin/) when you retrieve the text later on.